# How to loop through a menu expander using java and selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Main Menu

option 1

option 2

option 3

option 4

option 5

Here when I click on the Main menu. rest of the options appear. I want to loop through all the options and click them.

```
    List<WebElement> elements =submenuclick.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='...']/ul/li"));
           for (WebElement element: elements) {
              System.out.println(element.getText());
        }
```

when i execute this, a no such element exception occurs.

Comment: Please provide html code for your element or share the url of the page.

Comment: When does the error occur? When you click on main menu or afterwards when trying to get the options?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Xpath for storing list element as below as it should be till **Unordered List**:

```
  List <WebElement> elements =submenuclick.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='...']/ul"));
```

Try Now.